# Routing issues with NGINX and NodeJS+ApolloServer 2.0

Tags: node.js, express, apollo-server

My project involves more than one Node apps listening on different ports running from different subdirectories:

```
/
|
|
+-----default (app for schandillia.com)
|
|
+-----graph
        |
        |
        +-----blog (app for graph.schandillia.com/blog)
        |
        |
        +-----abc (app for graph.schandillia.com/abc)
```

Currently, I have a `server.js` for each app in its root folder (e.g., `/graph/blog/server.js` for the app, **graph.schandillia.com/blog**)

The `/graph/blog/server.js` file runs an **Apollo Server 2.0** for GraphQL and uses Express as a middleware. Here's the route definition in this middleware:

```
// GraphQL: Schema
const server = new ApolloServer({
  typeDefs,
  resolvers,
  playground: {
    endpoint: `/blog`, /* populates the playground endpoint box below the tab-strip. */
    settings: require('./playground.json')
  }
});

// Express: Initialize
const app = express();
// Middleware: GraphQL route
server.applyMiddleware({
  app,
  path: '/'
});
```

As you can see the `path` field is set to `/` (accessible as `https://graph.schandillia.com/blog`) here. However, I want it to point to a `/test` slug instead: `https://graph.schandillia.com/blog/test`. But setting `path` to `/test` returns an error (`Cannot GET /blog/test`).

Any suggestions?

Comment: Did you manage to solve that?